# Mutual information between independent measurement of two dependent random variables

Tags: information-theory

Suppose I have two dependent random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$. I perform independent measurement on each of these two variables, and we denote the output random variable as $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, respectively. By independent measurement, I mean that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are conditional independent given $X_1$ (or $X_2$).

Is it possible to express $I(Y_1, Y_2)$ in terms of $I(X_1,X_2)$ in a simple form? This feels like this problem must have been worked on before, but I couldn't find any references to it. I'd appreciate any hint as to how to approach this.

EDIT:
As requested, by conditional independence, I mean $P(Y_1,Y_2|X_1) = P(Y_1|X_1)P(Y_2|X_1)$ and $P(Y_1,Y_2|X_2) = P(Y_1|X_2)P(Y_2|X_2)$. By measurement, I just meant $Y_2$ depends on $X_2$ directly, so think of $X_2$ as input to a noisy channel and $Y_2$ as the output, and same for $X_1$. So in summary, two correlated input, each sent through two separate independent channels, and I'm interested in an expression for the mutual information (MI) of the outputs in terms of MI of inputs

Comment: "$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are conditionally independent given $X_1$ (or $X_2$)" is unclear (to me) – can you spell that out explicitly? Do both go with both, or just $1$ with $1$ and $2$ with $2$? Also, what do you mean by "performing a measurement on a random variable"?

Comment: @joriki I've added an edit, hopefully that made thing clearer? you can ignore the part about measurement, that is just to say that Y2 depends on X2, same for X1 and Y1